# Combining XAML with c#

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, code-behind

I am trying to write a auto generated SudokuBoard, which is generated in code behind. But for the layout i want to set it into a Dockpanel on the center Position.
Is there any option that I can combine it?

At the moment my `XAML` doens´t have any attributes. So I set the Generated Grid in the View like this: (From xaml.cs file)

```
this.Content = __grid;
```

Second thing, Is there any option to set my Textfield just to a numeric one, or better can I easily change the allowed chars ?
Need just numbers from 1-9 allowed

Answer (score 0):

In the second one Answer is

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="txtNo" TextChanged="txtNo_TextChanged_1" MaxLength="1" />
```

XAML.CS:

```
private void txtNo_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtnum = sender as TextBox;
    if (txtnum != null && txtnum.Text != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var num = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum.Text);
            txtnum.Text = num.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtnum.Text = string.Empty;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

or

the same event, pass the txtnum.Text value into your regular expression  method. write your self the regular expression method.

Comment: Can i write it in my loop for every Textbox in c#? Something like `textbox.TextChanged = "txtNo_TextChanged_1";` ? Or is it not possible on this way? Don´t have an option to do this in xaml so far

Answer (score 0):

To my Second one, I did it like this:
in xaml.cs

```
__txtBoxes[__col][__row].TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(InputChanged);
```

later in code:

```
protected void InputChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (tb != null && tb.Text != null)
    {
        try
        {
            var num = Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text);
            tb.Text = num.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tb.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Still don´t know how to set this in the dockpanel